# Why beautifulsoup is not showing any result?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I tried this but i didnt get any results. The program simply run & end with exit code 0. Everything before the for loop works fine (i checked with print() function).

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def webscrawling(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone" + str(page)
        sourcecode = requests.get(url)
        plaintext = sourcecode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class' : 'title'}):
            show = link.get('href')
            print(show)
        page += 1

webscrawling(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I run your code with printing the source code of url. These are the results:

```
<Response [404]>
<Response [404]>
```

As you can see we can't get any response. You can also try to connect these links from your browser you will get 404 error. The problem is because of there is no such webpages.

But there is no problem with your code except the urls. For example this is your code as edited by me. I commented in the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def webscrawling(max_page):
        page = 1;
        while page <= max_page:
                url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone" #this is a valid url if we remove the page
                sourcecode = requests.get(url)
                print(sourcecode) #i printed this for knowing the response from server (200 means OK)
                plaintext = sourcecode.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext, "html.parser")
                for link in soup.findAll('a',{'class' : 'title'}):
                        show = link.get('href')
                        print(show)
                page+=1
webscrawling(1)
```

and here is the output of edited code:

```
<Response [200]>
/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/219
/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/296
/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/286
```

Edit:
Okay the website is exists. We can go through this site "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone" there is no problem. But in your code you are not going to this site. You are going somewhere else. Your program requesting to "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone1" the difference between them is the last char of urls. For seeing better:

```
https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone
https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone1
```

as you can see there is difference between this links. Your program is initializing url in this line:

```
url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone"+str(page)
```

as you can see you have str(page) in the end of the url. Which is reason of our problem. If you remove +str(page) from this line

```
url = "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone"
```

the url will be correct.

Comment: Idk but i still can get into webscraper.io website. the website says that it is a website for testing webscraping.

Comment: "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone1" when you run your code your program tries to connect this link and there is no such webpage. Is it possible to you are going to "https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone" url (without the page number)?

Comment: I can explain more on my answer if you want. Just let me know if you need more help.

Comment: no. i searched webscraper.io & then i could go into the website. but i couldn't from the link. Yes, it would be a great help if you can give me some knowledge on it

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<a class='title'>` on the website you are viewing ([https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone1](https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone))

Comment: <a href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/246" class="title" title="Lenovo Legion Y520-15IKBM">Lenovo Legion Y5...</a>

i found this from the website just now. is it not the way to use beautifulsoup? @incarnadine

Comment: The website you are trying to scrape (above) doesn't exist